# map multiple elements with same key in F#

Tags: arrays, list, algorithm, arraylist, f#

Suppose two sorted lists with same length, key value list `let k = [1;1;2;2;3;3]`, and a number list`let n = [1;2;3;4;5;6]`. The ith position on both lists maps with each other, meaning the element `n=1` has a key value of `k=1`, `n=2` has a key value of `k=1`... so on.

How to create a list that maps multiple elements with same key value in F#?

So the output would be in a format `[[n1;n2;key];[n1;n2;key]...]`, the example output is `[[1;2;1];[3;4;2];[5;6;3]]`.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is a map data-structure, so i would use one, instead of implementing it yourself with a bunch of list functions you can convert your two lists in such a way

```
let k = [1;1;2;2;3;3]
let n = [1;2;3;4;5;6]

let mapKeyToValues keys values =
    let folder m k v =
        m |> Map.change k (function
            | Some old -> Some (v :: old)
            | None     -> Some [v]
        )
    List.fold2 folder Map.empty keys values
```

Now with

```
let r = mapKeyToValues k n
```

You get a data-structur like

```
Map [
    1, [2; 1] 
    2, [4; 3]
    3, [6; 5]
]
```

This would be equivalent to the JSON-Object

```
{
    "1": [2,1],
    "2": [4,3],
    "3": [6,5]
}
```

Usually you could write

```
let r = Map (List.zip k n)
```

This way, out of a tuple with `(k,v)` you create such a map-datastructure. But a new key, just ovverrides an older, so you get

```
Map [
    (1, 2)
    (2, 4)
    (3, 6)
]
```

That's the reason why you need `Map.change`. You go through every `(key,value)` of a list with `List.fold2` and then add it to the map data-structure. If a key is not present (the `None` case) you create a list as a value with your only value. In the `Some` case a key was already added, and you add your value to the list that is already present.

In this example i suppose the order of the values doesn't matter. If you want the same order as they appear in the value list, you must use `List.foldBack2` instead of `List.fold2`. But you must change the order of some arguments. This should be an exercise for you, to understand it better.

There is a `Map` module with different functions to work with such a data-structure, and it also provides things like `Map.map`, `Map.filter`, `Map.fold`, `Map.find`, ... and so on. So use this instead. If really needed you also could use `Map.toList` to transform it back to a list again, or use `Map.fold`.

---

Anyway as a reminder, as some people use (`List.zip` and then `List.map`) or  (`List.zip` and then `List.fold`). There is a `List.map2` and `List.fold2` that does this in one operation instead of two.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by "zipping" the two lists together and then grouping by the key:

```
let groupByKey keys numbers =
    List.zip keys numbers
    |> List.groupBy fst
    |> List.map (fun (key, values) -> key, (values |> List.map snd))

groupByKey k n // [(1, [1; 2]); (2, [3; 4]); (3, [5; 6])]
```

The above version of the function doesn't have the exact output format that you specified, but it is a more structured output, where each item in the list is a tuple of the key and the list of values for that key. This might be preferred for cleaner code, depending on what you're going to do with the result.

To get your specified format it can be changed slightly:

```
let groupByKey keys numbers =
    List.zip keys numbers
    |> List.groupBy fst
    |> List.map (fun (key, values) -> [
        yield! values |> List.map snd
        yield key 
    ])

groupByKey k n // [[1; 2; 1]; [3; 4; 2]; [5; 6; 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you are looking for is `Seq.zip`, which takes two sequences (list are sequences) and gives back a sequence of pairs.

Also note you specified your lists with commas, but F# uses semi-colons to separate list elements.

```ml
let keys = [ 1; 1; 2; 2; 3; 3 ]
let values = [ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6 ]

let map =
  values
  |> Seq.zip keys
  |> Seq.groupBy (fun (k, v) -> k)
  |> Seq.map (fun (k, vs) -> k, vs |> Seq.map snd |> Seq.toList)
  |> Map.ofSeq

printfn "%A" map

// map [(1, [1; 2]); (2, [3; 4]); (3, [5; 6])]
```

To get the format you are looking for (although I think you should consider a `Map`) you can unpack it like so:

```ml
let mapList =
  map
  |> Map.toSeq
  |> Seq.map (fun (k, vs) -> vs @ [ k ])
  |> Seq.toList

printfn "%A" mapList

// [[1; 2; 1]; [3; 4; 2]; [5; 6; 3]]
```